# Querying Last Column in a text file using apache-drill

Tags: apache-drill

I am unable to get the last column value Any suggestions, Selecting columns[2]   or the last column name does not work

```
I have the text file as 

PolicyID~Name~AccountID
1~ABC Holdings~12
2~XYZ Insurance~2

When i do a Select * from dfs.root it works
```

When i do either AccountID or columns[2] i get an error.

How do i query the last column in drill?..I get the following error when i query the last column

org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 32384, length: 4 (expected: range(0, 16384)) Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: dba982b9-0517-4ab2-a61f-dbf737c253da on 10.100.94.28:31010]

Comment: org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: IndexOutOfBoundsException: index: 32384, length: 4 (expected: range(0, 16384)) Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: dba982b9-0517-4ab2-a61f-dbf737c253da on 10.100.94.28:31010]